# ng-2 Charts: can't get bar chart axis to start at 0

Tags: html, angular, charts, ng2-charts

I am trying to use [ng-2 Charts](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/) so that I can have a simple responsive barchart in my angular application.

The numbers in my data set are pretty small. The smallest is 0 and the largest is 5. Most of the time the numbers come within 1 point of each other. For example [4, 4.1, 4] is pretty common. For this reason, I need the Y Axes to start at 0 and end at 5.

Currently, my chart looks like this with the above data set

[image: NG Charts]

Because it's automatically setting the bast of the chart at 4, my other two bars don't show at all. This isn't what I want. Upon googling the issue, I came across a few posts that recommend putting the following in your optionsVariable

```
  scales : {
    yAxes: [{
       ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          max : 5,
        }
    }]
  }
```

Here are posts I tried first :

- [Unable to make y-axis to begin at zero on Charts.js v2.1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37573689/unable-to-make-y-axis-to-begin-at-zero-on-charts-js-v2-1-4?rq=1)
- [set my chart min yaxis to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43525378/set-my-chart-min-yaxis-to-0)

But this did nothing.

Here is my full Bar Chart component

```
  public barChartOptions: any = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
    responsive: true,
    optionsVariable : {
      scales : {
        yAxes: [{
           ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              max : 5,
            }
        }]
      }
    }
  };

  public barChartLegend: boolean = false;


  @Input() barChartLabels: string[];
  @Input() chartColors: string[];
  @Input() barChartData: any[];
  @Input() barChartType: string;



  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

Here are the versions I'm using

> ```
> "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
> "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
> ```

And here is the javascript I'm inserting at idex.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

I also found this post 
[how to set start value as "0" in chartjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37922518/how-to-set-start-value-as-0-in-chartjs)

Edit 1 :

So I edited my BarChartOptions

```
  public barChartOptions: any = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true,
    options : {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero : true
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  };
```

But this did nothing.

I figured I'd try more options while I was at it

```
  public barChartOptions: any = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true,
    options : {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero : true,
            min: 0,
            max: 5
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  };
```

But this also did nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Edit : Full componenet mockup since people  have asked

bar-chart.component.html

```
<div>
  <div style="display: block">
    <canvas baseChart
            [datasets]="barChartData"
            [labels]="barChartLabels"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [legend]="barChartLegend"
            [chartType]="barChartType"
            [colors]="chartColors"
            ></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

bar-chart.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-bar-chart',
  templateUrl: './bar-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bar-chart.component.css']
})
export class BarChartComponent implements OnInit {

  public barChartOptions: any = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: false,
    options : {
      scales : {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  };

  public barChartLegend: boolean = false;


  @Input() barChartLabels: string[];
  @Input() chartColors: string[];
  @Input() barChartData: any[];
  @Input() barChartType: string;



  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Here is where I call the bar-chart component from 'results.component.html'

```
<app-bar-chart [barChartType]="programQualityBarChartType" [barChartData]="programQualityBarChartData" [barChartLabels]="programQualityLabels" [chartColors]="programQualityColors"></app-bar-chart>
```

And since I'm setting a lot of these values in the parent component, here is the typescript related to the chart from 'results.component.ts'

```
  populateCharts() {
    /*Program quality*/
    this.programQualityColors = [
      {
        backgroundColor: ['red', 'yellow', 'blue']
      }
    ];

    this.programQualityBarChartType = 'horizontalBar';
    this.programQualityLabels = ['Assessment & Diagnostics', 'Development', 'Performance Management'];
    this.programQualityBarChartData = [
      {data: [this.programQuality.assessment, this.programQuality.development, this.programQuality.performance], label: 'Program Quality'},
    ];
  }
```

Comment: Can you include your component markup?

Comment: It looks like you are nesting your options object too deply (c&p a bit too much? ;-) ). Check http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/ how the options object should look like and make sure your `barChartOptions` variable reflects this. Then pass it via the `options` property to your ng2-charts component.

Comment: I'm a bit confused @TommyF I am pretty sure the structure of my barChartOptions object is correct. Seems like I'm following the documentation correctly. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have add an answer and its work with the latest version of chart js https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng2-chart

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your option object has wrong structure you don't need extract option property.

set the y axes to begin at zero

```
  public chartOption = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

set x axes to begin at zero

```
  public horizontalChartOption = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

*template*

```
<h1> Type : bar</h1> 
    <canvas baseChart width="400" height="400"
                [data]="lineChartData"
                [labels]="lineChartLabels"
                [legend]="false"
                chartType="bar"
                [options]="chartOption"
                ></canvas>

</div>
<div>
<h1> Type : Horizontal Bar</h1> 

    <canvas baseChart width="400" height="400"
                [data]="lineChartData"
                [labels]="lineChartLabels"
                [legend]="false"
                chartType="horizontalBar"
                [options]="horizontalChartOption"
                ></canvas>

</div>
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng2-chart)

Answer (score 6):

```
public chartOption = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`optionsVariable` should be `options`

Comment: Originally I was using optionsVariable. But as you can see in later variations I've updated it. I'm still having issues.